# Subgroup analysis of separate RCTs

Tags: experiment-design

If I have an RCT with one treatment (group1) and a control (group2), and another RCT that was done separately again with one treatment (group3) and a control (group4).

Would the overlapping subgroups be statistically equivalent to do a multiple comparison test?
Two treatments (group1+3),
Treatment from first RCT only (group1+4),
Treatment from second RCT only (group2+3),
Controls from both RCT (group2+4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by:

> Would the overlapping subgroups be statistically equivalent to do a
> multiple comparison test?

but combining results from multiple studies is known as meta-analysis and is a full subject in its own right.

Simply combining the results in the way you seem to be suggesting sounds like a very bad idea. The different RCTs will have different populations, different inclusion and exclusion criteria, and possibly different treatments and controls (e.g. often the "control" is "normal treatment" which could be different).

Comment: Thanks @peter-flom!  FWIW, the "control" in both cases are not treated with anything.  I did "feel" it's a bad idea, but I don't know how to explain it properly.

Comment: to answer your question, I wanted to understand if the subgroups can be treated as a 4-cell test. Two treatment vs first treatment only vs second treatment only vs no treatment at all.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "No".  The complex answer is "do meta-analysis"

Comment: @PeterFlom What if the two experiments were done at the same time, on non-overlapping samples from the same populations?

Comment: That might be OK.